# Can we use apex and visualforce pages with Site.com?

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com, force.com-sites, site.com

Recently, I worked on a custom development where I used Force.com sites to enable access to some visualforce pages to end users without any authentication. For designing the VF pages, I used Bootstrap and jQuery.

Now, Before some days, I got to know about the site.com and it's capability to design pages with lesser time and better designs.

So, I just wanted to know that Is it possible to convert the whole thing which I have created with Force.com sites into Site.com ? Can I use apex and vf pages in site.com and also the similar functionality like "Rerender", "Render", "ActionFunctions" with Site.com also ?

Thanks,
Shankar

Answer (score 2):

> **Site.com** does not allow you to use Visualforce and apex . site.com supports HTML,CSS,Javascript and also there are special elements called repeaters and there are content blocks where you can pull data from objects on the block.

Again complex logics implemented using ReRender and Render is not possible in site.com .

One advantage of the site.com is its ability to Support controlled contributor or "content editor" access to pages after they've been built.

A form element provides facility to capture data in custom object but none of the Visualforce compoenets we can use .We can use JS libraries and also bootstrap library  .All the reRender and Render logic needs to be handled via jquery i guess .

You can go through site.com implementation [guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook_siteforce/wb_siteforce.pdf) for reference to gain more insight

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no, and here's why:

Site.com is a content management system that enables easy creation and management of a website's content. There is access to SFDC data through [Data Repeaters](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_data_repeater.htm&language=en_US) and [Data Connections](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_data_page_connection.htm). You can also create forms and web-to-lead interactivity through Site.com. And you have full use of front-end code, such as JavaScript and CSS.

But Site.com sites exist outside the flow of your Apex code and VF pages. So the answer is no, you're not able to use Apex code or VisualForce tags inside of Site.com.